# Qt + Sqlite, поиск без учета регистра (Кириллица)

Tags: c++, qt

Работаю в Qt Creator, БД Sqlite 3. Вроде погуглил - ответов много, но что-то большинство либо объяснены туманно, либо вовсе в моём случае не сработали.

```
QString srch = "%" + arg1 + "%"; //строка поиска
if (arg1.count(' ') == arg1.size()) { //если пусто - выводим весь список
    UpdateClients();
} else{ //если нет - вытаскиваем из бд клиентов с именами LIKE srch
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("SELECT id, companyName FROM clients WHERE companyName LIKE :search");
    query.bindValue(":search", srch);
    query.exec();
    clientsModel->setQuery(std::move(query));
    ui->listView->setModelColumn(1);
```

Поиск сам по себе работает исправно, если говорить о цифрах, латинице. Но с кириллицей такой фокус не прокатывает. А учитывая, что поиск идет в БД с клиентами (ОАО, ЗАО) и прочими интересными аббревиатурами, всё же нужно это как-то фиксить.

Всем спасибо

Answer (score 1):

а что мешает искать в одном регистре?

```
query.prepare("SELECT id, companyName FROM clients WHERE upper(companyName) LIKE :search");
query.bindValue(":search", srch.toUpper());
```

Comment: То, что upper() не работает для кириллицы в SQlite  в стандартном её виде.

Comment: https://rsdn.org/forum/cpp.qt/3726220.flat нужен sqlite+icu

Comment: хотя честно говоря не понимаю зачем все еще пользуются sqlite. не проще использовать что-то нормальное? тот же firebird embeded к примеру